# Saving path of pdf file in internal storage into Sqlite

Tags: android, pdf, android-sqlite

I am new to android and i am making an application which is take information from visitor's and make a pdf from it and save it internal storage,it also have the option for printing the information via printers connected through wifi

Here is my main java file Visitor_pass -

```
package com.example.sayedshazeb.practical1;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.print.PrintManager;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.CancellationSignal;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.print.PageRange;
import android.print.PrintAttributes;
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.print.PrintDocumentInfo;
import android.print.pdf.PrintedPdfDocument;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;


public class Visitor_pass extends ActionBarActivity implements ImageAndTextContainer {

    ImageView iv;
    public Context c;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_visitor_pass);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

             Button cbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.captureimage);
        cbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);

            }
        });



        Button pbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.print);

    pbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            printDocument(v);

        }
    });

        Button s =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Dbsave);

        s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void printDocument(View view)
    {

        // Get a PrintManager instance
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        // Give the job a name.
        String jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) +
                " Document";

        // Start a print job, passing a printDocumentAdapter as
        //argument to handle the generation of a print document
        MyPrintDocumentAdapter printDoc = new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(this);
        printManager.print(jobName, printDoc, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getImage() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        Bitmap image = null;
        // Get the image
        if ((imageView.getDrawable()) != null) {
            // Send it to the print helper
            image = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        }
        return image;
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public class MyPrintDocumentAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter
    {
        private ImageAndTextContainer imageAndTextContainer;
        Context context;
        private int pageHeight;
        private int pageWidth;
        public PdfDocument myPdfDocument;
        public int totalpages = 1;
        String pts;
        String ats;
        String cts;


        public MyPrintDocumentAdapter(ImageAndTextContainer container) {
            this.context =context;
            this.imageAndTextContainer = container;
        }


        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {
            myPdfDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, newAttributes);

            pageHeight =
                    newAttributes.getMediaSize().getHeightMils()/1000 * 72;
            pageWidth =
                    newAttributes.getMediaSize().getWidthMils()/1000 * 72;

            if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled() ) {
                callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                return;
            }

            if (totalpages > 0) {
                PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder = new PrintDocumentInfo
                        .Builder("print_output.pdf")
                        .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
                        .setPageCount(totalpages);

                PrintDocumentInfo info = builder.build();
                callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true);
            } else {
                callback.onLayoutFailed("Page count is zero.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {



            for (int i = 0; i < totalpages; i++) {
                if (pageInRange(pages, i))
                {
                    PdfDocument.PageInfo newPage = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth,
                            pageHeight, i).create();

                    PdfDocument.Page page =
                            myPdfDocument.startPage(newPage);

                    if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                        callback.onWriteCancelled();
                        myPdfDocument.close();
                        myPdfDocument = null;
                        return;
                    }
                    drawPage(page, i);
                    myPdfDocument.finishPage(page);
                }
            }

            try {
                myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(
                        destination.getFileDescriptor()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                callback.onWriteFailed(e.toString());
                return;
            } finally {
                myPdfDocument.close();
                myPdfDocument = null;
            }

            callback.onWriteFinished(pages);
        }


        private boolean pageInRange(PageRange[] pageRanges, int page)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<pageRanges.length; i++)
            {
                if ((page >= pageRanges[i].getStart()) &&
                        (page <= pageRanges[i].getEnd()))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


        private void drawPage(PdfDocument.Page page,
                              int pagenumber) {
            Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

            pagenumber++; // Make sure page numbers start at 1

            int titleBaseLine = 72;
            int leftMargin = 54;


            EditText pt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textname);
            EditText ct = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textphone);
            pts = pt.getText().toString();
            EditText at = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textaddress);
            ats = at.getText().toString();

            cts = ct.getText().toString();

            DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
            int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
            String d = ""+day;
            int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
            String m = ""+month;
            int year = datePicker.getYear();
            String y=""+year;

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize(40);
            canvas.drawText("Visitor Details " + pagenumber, leftMargin, titleBaseLine, paint);
            paint.setTextSize(25);
            canvas.drawText("Name :", leftMargin, titleBaseLine + 400, paint);
            canvas.drawText(pts ,leftMargin + 110,titleBaseLine + 400,paint);
            canvas.drawText("Address :",leftMargin,titleBaseLine + 450,paint);
            canvas.drawText(ats ,leftMargin + 110,titleBaseLine + 450,paint);
            canvas.drawText("Number :",leftMargin,titleBaseLine + 500,paint);
            canvas.drawText(cts ,leftMargin + 110,titleBaseLine + 500,paint);
            canvas.drawText("Date :" ,leftMargin,titleBaseLine + 550,paint);
            canvas.drawText( d + "/" +m+"/"+y  ,leftMargin+110,titleBaseLine + 550,paint);
            Rect imageRect = new Rect(100, 100, canvas.getWidth() - 240, canvas.getHeight() / 2 - 10);
            drawImage(imageAndTextContainer.getImage(), canvas, imageRect);





        }
        private void drawImage(Bitmap image, Canvas canvas, Rect r) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(image, null, r, new Paint());
        }






    }

}
```

And Here is my main Xml file-

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Visitor_pass"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Visitor&apos;s Pass"
        android:id="@+id/visitorpass"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/textname"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:hint="Enter visitor&apos;s name"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/textaddress"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:hint="Enter Address"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/textphone"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="Enter Number" />

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Capture Image"
        android:id="@+id/captureimage"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save "
        android:id="@+id/Dbsave"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Print"
        android:id="@+id/print"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Discard"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the print_dialog xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now i want to save the path of a pdf file created and saved in internal storage to be saved in my sqlite database. I know how to store values into database i just wanna know how to get the path of a file stored in my internal storage??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"i just wanna know how to get the path of a file stored in my internal storage??"
Have you tried [getFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)()? Example.

```
String path = this.getFilesDir().toString()+"/"+nameOfFile;
```

Comment: sorry to ask but i don't know how to use it in my action listener.I am a noob ,sorry to ask such a silly question

Comment: In your button click listener? the "this" keyword wont find getFilesDir() because its now referring to the Button. "this" is just the context, so you could access it like this as well Visitor_pass.this.getFilesDir(), and i think this will work too  getBaseContext().getFilesDir();
 and getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

This method returns the primary external storage directory.
For example, if you have a folder called /pdf, so the path of your file will be:

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pdf/" + <pd_file_name>`

*Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.*

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)

Comment: Don't forget the part about permissions